# How can a viewcontroller findout what viewcontroller called it?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a tableviewcontroller named ReadingMaintView. Each row has a label and a data collection control, example Reading Date has a textfield. In order to allow the user to use their thumb to scroll though a datepicker to select the date they want to be placed into the textfield for Reading Date I have another ViewController called AccessoryViewController. All that is on this view is a datepicker. When the user touches the accessorydetails button I have a segue to launch the AccessoryViewController. This is so the user can select the date they want.

Now, I would like to have any Viewcontroller be able to call AccessoryViewController to a date it needs. This means the AccessoryViewController needs to know the name of the calling ViewController so it can segue back. How can I do this ? I have set up a prepare for segue in ReadingMaintView and it triggers when I touch the accessorybutton. But what do I have to do in AccessoryViewController to retrieve the name of called (in this case ReadingMaintView) to do the callback?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, here's a couple of suggestions. Either pass the `ReadingMainView` as a parameter in the constructor for your `AccessoryViewController`

```
public class AccessoryViewController : UIViewController {
    public AccessoryViewController(UIViewController parent) {}
}
```

(Edit: @LarryOBrian is of course correct. This is already handled by the `ParenViewController` property, so it not a very good suggestion...)

or make your `AcessoryViewController` emit an event that the controller launching it can register an event handler on

```
// Somewhere in ReadingMaintView
var accessoryViewController = new AccessoryViewController();
accessoryViewController.ActionCompleted += (eventArgs) => {}
```

Comment: Hmm...I see what you mean. I will give it a try.

Comment: I actually quite like the idea of emitting an event that can be reacted to: in general, emitting an event and having things react is more robust than trying to "push" state.

Answer (score 0):

Every `UIViewController` has a `ParentViewController` property of type `UIViewController`. Or, you can grab the `UIWindow`'s `RootViewController` and work your way down with `ChildViewControllers` if you're way down in the hierarchy.

Also, I may be misunderstanding your use-case, but it seems like you might just call `UIViewController.PerformSegue(String identifier)`.

Comment: Thanks Larry. I am going try your PerformSegue idea.